# Any idea why my textContent does not change my "WELCOME" message?

Tags: javascript, html

[unable to change text from JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QNCr.png)

Comment: You have a typo in getElementById, also please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`(only one capital).
Normally, your JS should work then.